# How to access Java Webservice hosted in Amazon Web Services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jax-ws

I upload my WAR file of a java webservice to Amazon Web Services with Trial. Now I need to access to this webservice from my local java application. 
 How can I obtain the WSDL URL?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose If Your URL is This :

```
http://example:1112/test
```

For Access WSDL URL You use:

```
http://example:1112/test?WSDL
```

And the wsdl will be delivered.

Comment: I am not sure how to find my URL either. That is why I am looking for someone who can guide me inside the AWS Console to find this information